# How to retrieve standard parameters via AMPScript => RequestParameter()

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

What I've tried:

Scenario A: Push subscriber key in an encrypted query string to a Cloud Page and process it further. Link generation method:

Email code (simplified):

```
SET @unsub_url = CloudPagesURL(999)
%%=RedirectTo(@unsub_url)=%%
```

Cloud Page code:

Trying to get standard subscriberKey parameter

```
SET @subscriberKey1 = RequestParameter("subscriberKey") => NULL VALUE
SET @SubscriberKey2 = RequestParameter("_subscriberkey") => NULL VALUE
SET @SubscriberKey3 = RequestParameter(_subscriberkey) => NULL VALUE
SET @SubscriberKey4 = RequestParameter(subscriberkey) => NULL VALUE
```

Scenario B: Push subscriber key in an encrypted query string to a Cloud Page and process it further. Link generation method:

Email code (simplified):

```
SET @unsub_url = CloudPagesURL(999, "SubscriberKey", _subscriberkey)
%%=RedirectTo(@unsub_url)=%%
```

Cloud Page code:

```
 SET @SubscriberKey = RequestParameter("SubscriberKey") => VALID SubscriberKey
```

Conclusions

```
CloudPagesURL(999, "SubscriberKey", _subscriberkey) => Redirect OK; Attribute: OK;

CloudPagesURL(999) => Redirect OK; Attribute: NULL;
```

How to retrieve "standard/default" subscriber key parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy Fix: Just use `_subscriberKey` or `AttributeValue(_subscriberKey)`. RequestParameter does not work with personalizationstrings.

`set @subscriberkey = _subscriberKey`

or

`set @subscriberkey = AttributeValue(_subscriberKey)`